# Solve the linear congruence $6x\equiv9\pmod{27}$. Your answer should be in the form of a set of congruence classes modulo 27.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

for this question I used the Euclidean Algorithm in order to get an equation with the format of: $6v+27w=1$. I got there eventually and my answer was $x\equiv 7\pmod{27}$.

I was told that this was wrong and the correct answer was supposed to be: 6, 15 and 24 modulo 27.

I do not understand how to get to this result and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*...in order to get an equation with the format of $6v+27w=1$.  I got there eventually*"  You can't get to that equation since it is false for all integer values of $v,w$.  The left hand side is a multiple of $3$.  The right hand side is not a multiple of $3$.  Contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $6x\equiv9\pmod{27}$, then $6x=27n+9$.

Divide both sides by three. And you get $2x=9n+3$.

$2x\equiv3\pmod{9}$, then multiple both side by 5. $x\equiv10x\equiv15\equiv6\pmod{9}$.

The answer is $x\equiv6\pmod{9}$.

6, 15, 24 are equivalent modulo 9.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response. Can you explain how I could find out that from x≡6 mod 9, that 15 and 24 are equivalent and a part of the answer as well? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: @walterman It is obvious that 15, 24 are equivalent to 6 modulo 9 because 15-6=9, 24-6=18...

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If you are going to edit the original, please use proper MathJax code. `\mod` gives the wrong spacing; it's not meant to be either the operator or the relation symbol. For the binary operator, use `\bmod`; for the parenthetical congruence version, use `\pmod`. Compare $a\equiv b\mod c$ (`a\equiv b\mod c`), $a\equiv b \bmod c$ (`a\equiv b\bmod c`), and $a\equiv b\pmod{c}$ (`\equiv b \pmod{c}`).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oooooo Thx A lot... I'm not used to MathJax...